# Fill array with multiple arrays and multiple masks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with classifier's prediction, with a dataframe where I removed NaN values before feeding the algorithm. After the prediction, I want to create a new array where, if there was a valid point in the original dataframe, it will take the prediction, in other case the thing gets complicated: if there was a NaN value in the dataframe, it has to check other two dataframes and take de point from the one that has valid value.

An example of what I need:

```
z = np.array([2, 4, 5, 7])
x = np.array([3, 6, 9, 8])
pred_value = 11

mask_z = z[z%2 == 0] # array([True, True, False, False])
mask_x = x[x%2 == 0] # array([False, True, False, True])
mask_pred = np.arary([True, True, False, True])
```

Now I want to create a new array and fill it taking value from three different arrays. Lets say that, where there is a `False` in `mask_pred`, I want to take `pred_value`. But if there is a `True` in `mask_pred` I need to check `mask_z` and `mask_x` so that if there is a `True` in `mask_z` but a `False` in `mask_x`, it will take `x` value (and the other way around). In case both `mask_z` and `mask_x` are `True`, then it will take a NaN value:

```
y = np.empty(mask_pred.shape)
y[~mask_pred] = pred_value
# Part to fix:
y[mask_pred] = if mask_z == True and mask_x == False then take x value; 
               if mask_z == False and mask_x == True then take z value;
               if mask_z == True and mask_x == True then fill with np.NaN

print(y)
array([3, NaN, 11, 7])
```

I need to figure out how to make the last part working with masks and not loops, in an efficient way for large arrays.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` for that. There might be even quicker ways to do it, but this one is quite simple.

First you initialize the arrays with all `np.nan`, this should save you the last step. And then you just use `np.where` to check for your conditions:

(Also I think in your example there was an mistake and `mask_z` and `mask_x` should be defined like this:)

```
mask_z = z%2 == 0 # array([True, True, False, False])
mask_x = x%2 == 0 # array([False, True, False, True])

y = np.full(mask_pred.shape, np.nan)
y[~mask_pred] = pred_value
# Part to fix
y = np.where(mask_pred & mask_z & ~mask_x, x, y)
y = np.where(mask_pred & ~mask_z & mask_x, z, y)

np.testing.assert_allclose(y, np.array([3, np.nan, 11, 7]))
```

Comment: What if x and z have different size respect to y? I understand this reasoning should be valid anyways, but I have the following error in my real scenario: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12981609,) (17932,) (12981609,)
. As I understand, when is True in the first part (three masks together), it should place one of the values of the array with shape (17932,); and if its False, then one of the last array. Why do I get that error and how to avoid it? Thanks